# Show/hide selected form with jQuery/CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

i try to make an jQuery function for hide/show a form based on the user's choice!

Here is my code that you will understand better.

```
…               
<p id="joinChoice" class="parent">
    <a href="" id="mastercardChoice"><span class="overlay"></span></a>
    <a href="" id="visaChoice"><span class="overlay"></span></a>
    <a href="" id="discoverChoice"><span class="overlay"></span></a>
</p>
…


    <div class="joinForm">
        <div id="noneForm"></div>
        <div id="mastercardForm"></div>
        <div id="visaForm"></div>
        <div id="discoverForm"></div>
    </div>
```

The span#overlay in  is a simple checkbox image replacement !

I just need a function for hide/view each form for selected Card type !

For the #joinChoice i've already make this :

```
    $('#joinChoice a').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('on')
        .siblings().removeClass('on');
  });
```

Could you help me more please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

I was missing an important line:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

That prevents the page to reload when clicking on the `<a>`s.

The HTML:

```
<p id="joinChoice" class="parent">
    <a href="" id="mastercardChoice" data-form-id="mastercardForm"><span class="overlay"></span></a>
    <a href="" id="visaChoice" data-form-id="visaForm"><span class="overlay"></span></a>
    <a href="" id="discoverChoice" data-form-id="discoverForm"><span class="overlay"></span></a>
</p>
```

The Javascript:

```
$('#joinChoice a').click(function (e) {

    // prevents the click event to propagate up the DOM tree
    // And thus, prevents the page to reload, in that case..
    e.preventDefault();

    var $this = $(e.target);

    // Reset others
    var $links = $this.siblings();
    $links.removeClass('on');
    $links.each(function(linkEl) {
      $( '#'+$(linkEl).data('form-id') ).hide();
    });

    // Activate user choice..
    $this.addClass('on')
    $('#'+$this.data('form-id')).show();

});
```

Comment: Thanks, work fine ! Just need to put an anchor in <a href="#masterCardForm"… for no refreshesing page ! Another way ?

Comment: They're literally hundreds of way! And they are all very similar in the end.. @LinkinTED posted another one below. I like `data-form-id` way cause it frees you from tightly coupled naming conventions. That way you can name your form whatever, it doesn't depends on any convention.

Comment: I've just a problem if the user choice change ! could u help me please? 

? Perhaps add var +1 for z-index css param ?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. Does it have something to do with your `.on` CSS class? It sounds like another issue (a CSS issue) unrelated to this one. If so, I recommend you to post a new question with the associated HTML _and CSS_ code.

Comment: Ok, here the link of new post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19952180/hide-show-selected-form-with-jquery-and-css

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

HTML

```
<p id="joinChoice" class="parent">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="mastercard"><span class="overlay">Mastercard</span></a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="visa"><span class="overlay">Visa</span></a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="discover"><span class="overlay">Discover</span></a>
</p>

<div class="joinForm">
    <div id="noneForm">noneForm</div>
    <div id="mastercardForm">mastercardForm</div>
    <div id="visaForm">visaForm</div>
    <div id="discoverForm">discoverForm</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.joinForm div {
    display: none;
}
.on {
    color: red;
    background: yellow;
}
```

jQuery

```
$('#joinChoice a').click(function(){
    $('#joinChoice a').removeClass('on'); /* remove class from all siblings */
    $(this).addClass('on'); /* add class to active sibling */

    $('.joinForm div').hide(); /* hide all other forms */
    var subElement = '#' + $(this).attr("id") + 'Form';
    $( subElement ).show(); /* show active form */
});
```

And a [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/24CHz/)